# What is the correct pyinstaller Command to make pysnmp executable work on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pysnmp

I am using the following:

- pysnmp 4.4.9
- Python 3.7.2
- pyinstaller 3.4

My code is very simple, the heart of it is below:

```
def snmpv2Get(ip_address):
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
               CommunityData(snmpv2Community),
               UdpTransportTarget([ip_address, 161]),
               ContextData(),
               ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')),
               ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0')),
               lookupMib=False)
    )
```

When converting the code to an executable using pyinstaller, I get this error trying to run the generated executable:

```
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: No module __SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB loaded at <pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder object at 0x000002788101EA20>
```

The command I am using for pyinstaller is as follows:

```
pyinstaller -y -F -i "icon.ico" SNMP.py --hidden-import="pysnmp.smi.mibs,pysnmp.smi.mibs.instances,pysnmp.smi.exval,pysnmp.cache"
```

Honestly, I don't want to modify *.spec file because each time I modified it, the command overrides *.spec contents, I don't know why.

Kindly, what is the correct command line to avoid this "No module" error. I have seen many threads with similar error message, but all of them dealt with the *.spec file, what I am looking for is the correct command line to use on windows, not *.spec file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PyInstaller could not resolve [`pysnmp`](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp) by its own so an easy solution is to use [`Tree`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes) class and embedding the library directory within the executable. After generating `spec` file add the Tree class. So your spec file should look like something like this (remember to replace the module path according to your Python path):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ...
)
a.datas += Tree("./env/Lib/site-packages/pysnmp", prefix='pysnmp')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
...
```

And finally generate your executable with (I suggest you not use your script name same as module name):

```
pyinstaller script.spec
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the contents of my *.spec file, it works very well for pysnmp and pyinstaller:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
# source: http://qaru.site/questions/8036799/pyinstaller-does-not-work-when-including-pysnmp

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files, collect_submodules

x = Tree('C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs',prefix='pysnmp/smi/mibs',excludes='.py')

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['SNMP.py'],
             pathex=['path to python file/'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pysnmp.smi.exval','pysnmp.cache'] + collect_submodules('pysnmp.smi.mibs') + collect_submodules('pysnmp.smi.mibs.instances'),
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          x,
          name='SNMP',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='icon.ico')
```